# windows 7 taskbar style and color issue

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

all of a sudden what i started my pc today the taskbar seems to be changed.

The taskbar is thin, the colors are toooo light and barely readable.

initially my performance settings were set to custom and i tried changing it to best appearance, but it remains the same.

im using a Acer Aspire with Windows 7 Home Basic

below is a screenshot
[image]

any help will be appreciated

Comment: quick check: RIGHT click on the start menu, select "properties" go to the "taskbar" tab and see if "Use Small Icons" is selected.

Comment: @Psycogeek yep. its selected. when i uncheck in the icons are becoming huge. but the background seems to be too light so the text are not readable

Comment: Did you go into personalisation? and reset the theme? it is just a color problem now, not a "font" issue right?